# Converting images into video

Tags: video, convert, avconv, video-conversion

I found a method on internet to use `avconv` to make a video from images, but the quality is very poor. I set the resolution but it didn't help.

```
avconv -i "franc%04d.jpg" -r 30 -s:v 1280x720 a.mkv
```

How can I choose the image compression and set the quality to best?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that with ffmpeg and imagemagic. Install them if they are not installed on your PC.

Do these steps in your terminal:

1. Create a directory for trying this solution, you better make a duplicate copy of the videos before trying this.

```
mkdir temp
```

2. Copy all of your images to that directory `temp` you have created.

```
cp *.JPG temp/.
```

3. Set the resolution of your images.

```
mogrify -resize 800x800  temp/*.JPG
```

4. Convert them to be get morphed for soft transitions and and make them a mp4 video.

```
convert temp/*.JPG -delay 10 -morph 10 temp/%05d.jpg
ffmpeg -r 25 -qscale 2  -i temp/%05d.jpg output.mp4
```

ffmpeg is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 14.04, but is in 15.04!

source: http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html

Comment: I get: "Option qscale (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) cannot be applied to input file temp/%05d.jpg -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file temp/%05d.jpg.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
"  and when this is corrected, "Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x3a84820] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended."

Answer (score 1):

You can use kdenlive to make image slide-shows as well as advance video editing.

[Download KDEnlive!](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdenlive/)